# python KeyError: 'DescendantFonts'

Tags: python, pdf

I'm trying to parse PDF file using PDFMiner, a common code format like this:

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, process_pdf
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from io import StringIO
from io import open
from subprocess import call
def readPDF(pdfFile):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, laparams=laparams)
    process_pdf(rsrcmgr, device, pdfFile)
    device.close()
    content = retstr.getvalue()
    retstr.close()
    return content
file_path = 'D:\\mytask\\file_test.pdf'
pdfFile = open(file_path, "rb")
outputString=readPDF(pdfFile)
print(outputString.replace(' ',''))
pdfFile.close()
```

This yields the following error:

```
WARNING:root:Invalid dictionary construct: [/Type, /Font, /Subtype, /Type0, 
/BaseFont, /ABCDEE+å¾®è½¯é, é», /Encoding, /Identity-H, /DescendantFonts, 
<PDFObjRef:15>, /ToUnicode, <PDFObjRef:297>]
WARNING:root:Literal required: é»
WARNING:root:Literal required: <PDFObjRef:15>
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
process_pdf(rsrcmgr, device, pdfFile)
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfinterp.py", line 707, in process_pdf
    interpreter.process_page(page)
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfinterp.py", line 642, in process_page
    self.render_contents(page.resources, page.contents, ctm=ctm)
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfinterp.py", line 650, in render_contents
    self.init_resources(resources)
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfinterp.py", line 280, in init_resources
    self.fontmap[fontid] = self.rsrcmgr.get_font(objid, spec)
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfinterp.py", line 162, in get_font
    dfonts = list_value(spec['DescendantFonts'])
KeyError: 'DescendantFonts'
```

But when I changed a new PDF file or turn into PyPDF2, it worked. Sincerely, whether PDFMiner or PyPDF, they do not work very well (obviously, the format of results are very different from what the Acrobat Reader shows). I wonder if there's a better PDF parser package for python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Without the PDF in question

Unfortunately you did not share the PDF in question.

The warning output of the dictionary in question

```
[
  /Type, /Font,
  /Subtype, /Type0,
  /BaseFont, /ABCDEE+å¾®è½¯é, é»,
  /Encoding, /Identity-H,
  /DescendantFonts, <PDFObjRef:15>,
  /ToUnicode, <PDFObjRef:297>
]
```

seems to indicate an invalid **BaseFont** name which is interpreted as a name (**/ABCDEE+å¾®è½¯é**) and a further object (**é»**) as can be seen by the comma in between. As a dictionary has to contain alternating key and value entries, this value split into two entries completely breaks the dictionary structure.

Thus, it appears that the PDF is broken, at least the dictionary this all is about.

If you share the PDF in question, we can check whether this analysis is correct or whether there is something else causing pdfminer to misinterpret the data and wrongly present them in the warning.

#### With the PDF in question

The OP meanwhile shared the PDF in question. In it the dictionary entry in question in a hex editor looks like this:

[image: hex editor screen shot]

Comparing the error message with this screen shot indicates that the `9B` and/or the `85` has been interpreted as a delimiter by pdfminer. Also the final `91` is dropped in the warning.

According to the specification, though,

- a name object is an atomic symbol uniquely defined by a sequence of any characters (8-bit values) except null (character code 0),
- any character in a name that is a regular character (other than NUMBER SIGN) may be written as itself (i.e. it needs not be written using a `#xx` notation), and
- all characters except the white-space characters and delimiters are referred to as regular characters, so in particular all bytes from 0x80 though 0xFF.

Thus, pdfminer is buggy where it interprets `9B` and/or the `85` as a delimiter.

In contrast to the original analysis (without the PDF at hand), the PDF is not broken in regard to this name object. (It does not follow the recommendation of the specification to use the hexadecimal notation for bytes from 0x80 though 0xFF, but this only is a recommendation, not a requirement.)

Comment: Please download the pdf file [here](https://pan.baidu.com/s/1bZFMXo) by yourself, it's not broken, I can read it with PyPDF and it seems pretty normal in acrobat pdf reader.

Comment: @m.yang You're right. This appears to be a pdfminer bug in the version you have.